# How to modify the json object data Through robot framework?

Tags: json, robotframework

I am getting the following improper JSON from some file to process it through the Robot framework.

```
{
"Name":"Naveen",
"Vechicle":"["Car"]"
}
```

so I want to make it proper by removing double inverted commas "" from array["Car"]

**Expectation is**

```
{
"Name":"Naveen",
"Vechicle":["Car"]
}
```

Comment: If it's supposed to be valid json, the better solution is to fix the code that generates the data. Are you able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only this kind of invalid json, you can use `Replace String` from [String Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html):

```
${invalid_json}=    Set Variable    { "Name":"Naveen", "Vechicle":"["Car"]" }
${valid_json}=    Replace String    ${invalid_json}    "["    ["
${valid_json}=    Replace String    ${valid_json}    "]"    "]
Log    ${valid_json}
```

It logs `{ "Name":"Naveen", "Vechicle":["Car"] }`, which is a valid json